# HTML text don't rendering as in code lines

Tags: html

I'm doing the blog template and I put "lorem ipsum" text in the post. The text has line spacing, but the preview does not display these spaces and the text consists of a single paragraph.
How it is rendering in preview : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQBrJw
How i want it to be: :  https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html

i want do this without `</br>` code or using css elements.

Comment: You mean you want the text in paragraph blocks? Couldn't you just put `<p>` and `</p>` at the beginning and end of each paragrah? Like this - https://jsfiddle.net/xfge6r8j/2/

Comment: you need to add < p> < /p> along with css - your example has - < p >
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel metuuam sem. Integer blandit consectetur mauris, non malesuada risus commodo id. Etiam ultrices vitae neque a convallis. Mauris pretium venenatis orci quis commodo. Ut vel facilisis est. In vel suscipit enim, sed porttitor justo. In vitae enim justo. Donec lacus nibh, cursus ac neque id, maximus eleifend leo. Aenean eleifend sapien sed purus sodales accumsan.
< /p >

p {
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}